# How can I get folder icons for the VS Code Material Icon Theme extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Material Icon theme not rendering some folder icons in my VS Code.

Can you explain how to solve this problem.

[image]

Material Icon theme supports for this folder icon but not rendering in my case.

[image]

And my settings.json seems all good.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot from the documentation might be a bit misleading. My understanding of how it actually works from glancing at the source code and settings is that for you to get those icons, you need to change the icon pack setting to `"react_redux"` (the default value is `"angular"`), which you can do by putting `"material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "react_redux"` in your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). And then the folder shouldn't actually be named "Redux-store", but instead ["store" or "stores"](https://github.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme/blob/d7c0fa80ac9b29f8c52d44ddc122d109db459611/src/icons/folderIcons.ts#L297), not "Redux-reducer", but instead ["reducer" or "reducers"](https://github.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme/blob/d7c0fa80ac9b29f8c52d44ddc122d109db459611/src/icons/folderIcons.ts#L297), and not "Redux-selector", but instead ["selector" or "selectors"](https://github.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme/blob/d7c0fa80ac9b29f8c52d44ddc122d109db459611/src/icons/folderIcons.ts#L297).

Comment: yes @starball finally i found from where the error causes... and I got solution.. The answer is same as you told above

Comment: @krishnAtiwari how did you find the solution yourself? Just curious.

Comment: Go to your `settings`, search `material-icon-theme`, and select option `react-redux` instead of `angular`. Now you can enjoy it works fine.